# Error trying to access WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services, iis-express

***Problem had been Fixed*** 
Following a tutorial on MSDN- I created and accessed a WCF services with the Northwind database just fine. With different data, I followed the same process: defined my ADO.NET entity model, created the data service, and enabled access to resources, but I am receiving an error. The error on the webpage only says "Request Error." I have IIS 8.0 express installed, both web.configs are similar, and WCF service is enabled.

I put a break point on InitializeService(), but it never hits that sub. I am not sure where to go from here.

## IIS Log file

> Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0
> Version: 1.0 
> Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip vcs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
> 2013-09-14 09:47:04 ::1 GET /tinytrots.svc - 50274 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+>>(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/29.0.1547.66+Safari/537.36 -> 307 0 0 769
> 2013-09-14 09:47:04 ::1 GET /tinytrots.svc/ - 50274 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+>   (Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/29.0.1547.66+Safari/537.36 - >500 0 0 608

## IIS TraceLogFiles

> ModuleName: ManagedPipelineHandler 
> Notification: EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
> HttpStatus: 500 
> HttpReason: Internal Server Error 
> HttpSubStatus: 0 
> ErrorCode: The operation completed successfully.(0x0)

## Event Viwer

> My Application logs says "The direcoty specified for caching compressed content C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\ISS Temporary Compressed Files\ Clr4IntegratedAppPool is invalid. Static compression is being disabled."

## The Data Service

```
Public Class tinytrots
Inherits DataService(Of TinyTrotsDBEntities)

Public Shared Sub InitializeService(ByVal config As DataServiceConfiguration)

config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Activities", EntitySetRights.All)
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Had to run this command to register the required script maps in IIS: 

>"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751527.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252.aspx

Comment: You should post this as answer - that way future users can see that this question has an answer (rather than having to read the comments). Plus you can self-accept the answer.

Comment: I cant because I don't have enough points. When I do, I will update it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to run this command to register the required script maps in IIS: >"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r

http://www.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751527.aspx

http://www.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252.aspx